# AWS Lambda Function Switches Excecution Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a number of Lambda functions. All but one of them use a fairly simple execution role called `ExecuteLambda`. The other one uses an almost identical execution role called `ExecuteLambdaWithS3Access`. The only difference is that this also grants access to S3.

For some reason, at what appears to be a random point in time, the execution role assigned to this latter Lambda function switches from `ExecuteLambdaWithS3Access` to `ExecuteLambda`. This breaks my asyncronous REST API because the Lambda function stops being able to write the results to S3. I then have to log into AWS Console and manually switch it back.

I've tried deleting the offending Lambda function and recreating it and it makes no difference.

I'd raise this with AWS but I only have the basic support plan, so I wanted to see if anyone here had any idea what might be causing this first.

Comment: Use CloudTrail Logs to find out when, and by whom, the role is being changed.

Comment: AWS Lambda surely does not _randomly_ switch a role in your Lambda Function.

Comment: I'm the only person who has access to the account. If someone has hacked into my account, it would be odd that that's the only thing they're doing.

Comment: Well it might not be random, but it seems like it. I've set up a CloudTrail log, so let's see what it tells me.

Comment: Last night I updated the function and the role switched. I discovered that `aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json` hadn't been updated when I originally changed the role to ExecuteLambdaWithS3Access. So there's a tip for you - if you change the role of a Lambda function, you need to manually change it in aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json as well.